# How do I find the count of a particular column [Model], based on another column [SoldDate] using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, such as SoldDate,Model and TotalSoldCount. How do I create a new column, 'CountSoldbyMonth' which will give the count of each of the  many models sold monthly? A screenshot describing the problem is given.
The ‘CountSoldbyMonth’ should always be less than the ‘TotalSoldCount’.

I am new to Python. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QMXI.png)

```
Date        Model  TotalSoldCount
Jan 19        A          4
Jan 19        A          4
Jan 19        A          4
Jan 19        B          6
Jan 19        C          2
Jan 19        C          2
Feb 19        A          4
Feb 19        B          6
Feb 19        B          6
Feb 19        B          6
Mar 19        B          6
Mar 19        B          6
```

The new df should look like this.

```
Date      Model     TotalSoldCount     CountSoldbyMonth
Jan 19     A               4                    3
Jan 19     A               4                    3
Jan 19     A               4                    3
Jan 19     B               6                    1
Jan 19     C               2                    2
Jan 19     C               2                    2
Feb 19     A               4                    1
Feb 19     B               6                    3
Feb 19     B               6                    3
Feb 19     B               6                    3
Mar 19     B               6                    2
Mar 19     B               6                    2
```

I tried doing

> df['CountSoldbyMonth'] = df.groupby(['date','model']).totalsoldcount.transform('sum')

but it is generating a different value.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! If you could please provide your data in a `code-formatted` way it will be easier for other members to form an answer. It would also be helpful if you could provide any code that you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: My apologies! I have edited my question in a more readable format.

Comment: @Leena, are you sure the last few rows are correct in your expected output? I'm thinking `CountSoldbyMonth` should be `2` and not `5` for the `Mar 19` `B` rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have this data set:

```
      date model  totalsoldcount
0   Jan 19     A             110
1   Jan 19     A             110
2   Jan 19     A             110
3   Jan 19     B              50
4   Jan 19     C              70
5   Jan 19     C              70
6   Feb 19     A             110
7   Feb 19     B              50
8   Feb 19     B              50
9   Feb 19     B              50
10  Mar 19     B              50
11  Mar 19     B              50
```

And you want to define a new column, `countsoldbymonth`. You can `groupby` the `date` and `model` columns and then `sum` the `totalsoldcount` with a transform and then create the new column:

```
s['countsoldbymonth'] = s.groupby([
    'date',
    'model'
]).totalsoldcount.transform('sum')

print(s)

      date model  totalsoldcount  countsoldbymonth
0   Jan 19     A             110               330
1   Jan 19     A             110               330
2   Jan 19     A             110               330
3   Jan 19     B              50                50
4   Jan 19     C              70               140
5   Jan 19     C              70               140
6   Feb 19     A             110               110
7   Feb 19     B              50               150
8   Feb 19     B              50               150
9   Feb 19     B              50               150
10  Mar 19     B              50               100
11  Mar 19     B              50               100
```

Or, if you just want to see the sums without creating a new column you can use `sum` instead of `transform` like this:

```
print(s.groupby([
    'date',
    'model'
]).totalsoldcount.sum())

date    model
Feb 19  A        110
        B        150
Jan 19  A        330
        B         50
        C        140
Mar 19  B        100
```

## Edit

If you just want to know how many sales were done in the month you can do the same `groupby`, but instead of `sum` use `count`

```
df['CountSoldByMonth'] = df.groupby([
    'Date',
    'Model'
]).TotalSoldCount.transform('count')

print(df)

      Date Model  TotalSoldCount  CountSoldByMonth
0   Jan 19     A               4                 3
1   Jan 19     A               4                 3
2   Jan 19     A               4                 3
3   Jan 19     B               6                 1
4   Jan 19     C               2                 2
5   Jan 19     C               2                 2
6   Feb 19     A               4                 1
7   Feb 19     B               6                 3
8   Feb 19     B               6                 3
9   Feb 19     B               6                 3
10  Mar 19     B               6                 2
11  Mar 19     B               6                 2
```

Comment: I tried using groupby and sum but it's not giving me the correct count.

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to help if you give code that let's the user experiment. In this case, I'd think taking your dataframe (df) & doing the following should work:

```
df['CountSoldbyMonth'] = df.groupby(['Date','Model'])['TotalSoldCount'].transform('sum')
```